# Expected consecutive "runs" when n coins are tossed

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

**Question** *n* coins are tossed, with each coin having probability *p* to turn up a head. Let a "run" denote a series of consecutive heads. For example, if we have THHTHTHH, then there are 3 runs. What is expected number of runs, as a function of *n* and *p*?

This is the solution I came up with:

First we want to construct a sequence with *r* runs and *s* heads. Let *n* be the total number of coin flips.

First we put down the *n-s* tails. Then, we choose r positions from the "gaps" between the tails to put our "runs". We have $ n-s+1 \choose r $ ways of doing this.

Then, we distribute our *s* successes into our *r* runs. This is equivalent to distributing *s* objects into *r* boxes where no box can be empty. So, we have $ s-1 \choose r-1 $ ways of doing this.

Each sequence formed using the above method has a chance of occurring equal to $ p^{s} \times (1-p)^{n-s} $

The value of $r$ ranges from 1 to $ \lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil $ and for each value of $r$ the value of s ranges from $r$ to $n-r+1$. I ignore the cases where there are 0 runs since they don't affect the expected value.

e.g. in a sequence of 7, there could be 1 to 4 runs, and consider the cases where there are 2 runs, we can have 2 or 3 successes.

So, the expected value would be:

$ \sum_{r=1}^{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil}{ \sum_{s}^{n-r+1}{r{n-s+1 \choose r}{s-1 \choose r-1}{p^s}{(1-p)}^{n-2}}} $

The solution should be $ p+(n-1)(1-p)p $. I wrote a program to calculate this double summation and I found that it *should* be correct.

However, I have no idea how to manually evaluate this monster double summation. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expected number of runs are either same for heads and tails or can differ by one. So finding expected number of runs is good enough?

Comment: Also I think there is a typo in your double summation - both sums have $r$ as variable, one of them should have been $s$? Did you manually check values for $n = 2, 3$ etc.? In any case your solution is complicated and you can get to the exact expression in a much easier way.

Comment: Ah yes, fixed the typo. Thanks for pointing that out. Yes I found a much easier way to do this problem, but I'm just wondering if it is possible to do it this way XD